# Is it currently possible to set up automated deployments on-premises using hosted source control?

Tags: deployment, azure-devops, release-management, ms-release-management

I've been searching for some time to find a way to set up automated deployments with our current setup, but have had no luck as most products seem to be geared for cloud based solutions.

We are using Visual Studio Online to manage our SDLC and source control (git). It's working great for us. We'd also like to set up automated deployments / release management, but our applications are deployed on-premises and only available when in the network. This won't change, the applications (or most) will never be open to the public.

Is there any product or tool for on-premises deployments that will integrate with a cloud based source control provider such as Visual Studio Online? I've looked at Octopus Deploy and installed it, but that also doesn't seem to fit the bill.

If it doesn't exist right now, that's fine too. **I should note that we can't afford to buy TFS and we don't really have the resources to manage TFS on premises.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visual Studio Online will have release management capabilities in the near future. The release management capabilities are currently in private preview to selected users only, but you can find out more [here](http://releasepreview.azurewebsites.net/) and [here](https://channel9.msdn.com/events/Build/2015/3-649).

Comment: Just when I was thinking this would be a neat tool to create for this problem, they've already got it coming! Awesome. Thanks for the information, this is what I was looking for - I'll be sure to keep an eye on this.

Comment: Also see [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charles_sterling/archive/2015/07/05/continuous-integration-lab-for-msit.aspx) blog post for yet more of an idea of what's coming. It's a little odd as it's a public post aimed at internal Microsoft IT people and as such refers to resources that aren't available to non-insiders right now. Possibly useful nevertheless.

Comment: Looking at this, I'm wondering if this will still meet my needs. Not sure if their "on prem" requires a public IP, which I won't have. We'll see!

Comment: Just to add to the answer, VSO release management will facilitate your cloud based as well as on-prem deployments. You'll need to set up agents on the target machines (cloud based or onprem whatever suits your needs) and VSO RM will be able to communicate to it. I bet the point is covered in the channel 9 video as well.

Comment: You won't need a Public IP on the target machines @DoctorOreo. An agent on those machines will take care of running your tasks for you.